# Rails - take(4) but the bottom not the top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have @comments which lets say has 17 records

What I want is the last 4: 14,15,16,17

I tried:

```
<% @comments.take(4).each do |comment| %>
```

But that returns the first 4.. How can I grab the last 4 comments, not the first 4

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also do:

```
@comments.last(4)...
```

Comment: This is the better solution of the two imo.

Answer (score 5):

```
<% @comments.reverse.take(4).each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: And if you want them in order (14,15,16,17) instead of (17,16,15,14), you can do @comments.reverse.take(4).reverse.each.

Comment: @Zach - yes, I was just thinking of adding that!